# how to write like facet.method=enum in query with spring solr

Tags: spring, solr, facet

in solr query...
 `facet.method=enum`

how spring data solr can do like above.

```
SimpleFacetQuery facetQuery = new SimpleFacetQuery(new Criteria(CrawlDocument.FIELD_CONTENT).contains(searchStr));
        facetQuery.setFacetOptions(new FacetOptions().addFacetOnField(CrawlDocument.FIELD_CONTENT).setFacetLimit(20));
```

????

please give tips

Comment: I tried to edit this just to format the code, but it wasn't enough changes to save the edits.  Then I wanted to fix the language, but there is something lost to understanding in "how spring data solr can do like above".  What do you mean?

Comment: i want to express 'facet.method=enum' using spring data solr API.

Answer (score 0):

It's depends on solrj-1.1.0 and spring-data-4.6.1.

```
@Test
public void testFacetMethodEnum()   throws SolrServerException {
    SimpleFacetQuery query = new SimpleFacetQuery();
    query.addCriteria(new Criteria("coumn_name1").is("value1"));
    query.addCriteria(new Criteria("coumn_name2").is("value2"));
    query.addProjectionOnField("projection_1");

    FacetOptions facetOptions = new FacetOptions("facet_field");
    facetOptions.setFacetLimit(1000);
    query.setFacetOptions(facetOptions);

    QueryParsers queryParsers = new QueryParsers();
    SolrQuery solrQuery = queryParsers.getForClass(query.getClass()).constructSolrQuery(query);
    solrQuery.setParam(FacetParams.FACET_METHOD, FacetParams.FACET_METHOD_enum);

    QueryResponse reponse = Your_SolrTemplate.getSolrOperations().getSolrServer().query(solrQuery);
    assertNotNull(reponse);
}
```